# Calling Nested Lambda Function in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.5

is that possible to call lambda function in nesting way

```
<?php
$func=function() use($something,$func /** as you know it will be undefined so what could be other way arround**/){
  if($something){
       $func();
  }
}
```

Comment: why down vote? isn't it related to PHP

Comment: these are allowed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-do-various-symbols-mean-in-php?rq=1 but real problems not allowed.

Comment: So in a definition of something you want to use the above said something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$func` is not defined yet when you pass it to `$func`. `$func` will only be defined right after the function definition, which is a little bit too late for this to work.

The easy work around is as follows:

```
$func = null;
$func = function() use (&$func) {

}
```

Comment: good one... I'd never thought of using references for this...

Comment: me too.............

Answer (score 0):

`use $func` can't succeed, because `$func` won't be defined until AFTER the lambda creation has completed and returned the lamba. PHP cannot time travel.

You also cannot do something like:

```
$func = '';
$func = function() use $something, $func ....;
```

While that gets around the `$func is not defined`, it also "locks" the value of `$func` into the lambda at the time the lambda's created:

```
php > $foo = 'bar';
php > $baz = function() use($foo) { echo $foo; };
php > $baz();
bar
php > $foo = 'qux';
php > $baz();
bar
```